# tf.placeholder() is not compatible with eager execution

Tags: python, tensorflow, placeholder, eager-execution

I am working on a project and am trying to replace this block of code with something that works. I am using version 2.5.0 of tensorflow and am faced with the following error.

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder'

When i used this.

tf.compat.v1.placeholder(dtype, shape=None, name=None)

```
  with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope("regression"):
    x = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 901])
    y, variables = regression(x)
```

This error occurs.

> ** RuntimeError: tf.placeholder() is not compatible with eager execution.**

kindly help me solve it.

Thanks!

Comment: For Tensorflow 2.x default Eager execution enabled. SInce `tf.placeholder` is removed from Tensorflow 2.x. It won't be compatible to eager execution. Disable the eager execution, in order to use `tf.compat.v1.placeholder` in Tf 2.x using, `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()`. Thanks!